# PDO returning incorrect, but duplicate, data. Key's not in database.

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to using $pdo statements so might be something simple I haven't yet read on php.net. I'm receiving duplicate results when querying the database.

**Result:**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [umeta_id] => 31
        [0] => 31
        [user_id] => 2
        [1] => 2
        [meta_key] => fbmeta
        [2] => fbmeta
        [meta_value] => someMetaValueStuff;
        [3] => someMetaValueStuff;
    )
```

The query is quite simple:

```
function getData(){
    global $pdo;
    $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usermeta WHERE meta_key = "fbmeta" LIMIT 0,30');
    $query->execute();

    return $query->fetchAll();
}

print_r( getData() );
```

The problem is that the named keys (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) DO exist, the numeric keys do not. How come the query returns these? And how do I prevent them from even being returned?

Comment: before anyone asks, yes I have manually checked and limited the database to a small collection, so the duplicates really do not exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's not duplicates, it's just the current `FETCH_MODE` you're using. To get as associative keys only you need to specify as such; by default it fetches as both.

Use like so:

```
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); // to fetch with numeric indexes
$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // to fetch with associative indexes
```

[fetchAll docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
[fetch docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: Cool that fixed it. Too bad I cant select 2 answers as answering, both you and Yogesh were at it at the same time.

Comment: @Nukeface I think its my first...:). But you can accept anyone's answer, its your choice...:)

Comment: Will do when the timer counts down, you guys were quick ;) Will choose this one though, the fetch docs went to the fetch function where I should've noticed the differences on my first look-through, and didn't.

Answer (score 11):

This is not duplicate data `fetchAll` returns data in numeric array as well as associative array.

See the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Use this for retrieving only associative array

```
return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score -1):

seems to do the trick for me. Put this on top

```
use Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared;
```

when ever fetching include pdo::fetch_assoc

```
return($pdo->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Comment: Seems your using this: https://github.com/illuminate/database

This does not solve the original issue, as this is not just plain PHP but an externally required package. Required either by your project, some framework or cms or another package dependency.